# Correlation between dependent gaussian random variables

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution

I have two vectors of n random variables each. The first vector $\vec{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is drawn i.i.d. according to $X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. The second is drawn from the first vector $\vec{y} = (y_1, \dots, y_n)$ where $Y_i \sim (X_i, \tau^2)$. We can alternatively write $Y_i = X_i + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim (0, \tau^2)$, though I'm not sure if this is useful or not. I would now like to calculate $\text{corr}(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$, but am having difficulty knowing when to treat $X$ as a random variable and when to treat it as fixed (as it is in the definition of $Y_i$).

Comment: Use the bilinearity of covariance, given that $\epsilon_i$ is independent of $X_i.$

Comment: Ignoring the vectors, the variance of $X_i$ is $\sigma^2$, the variance of $Y$ is $\sigma^2+\tau^2$ and the covariance between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ is $\sigma^2$